# Undefined method error on .sum

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sum

I have a error that I can't find the solution.

When I run:

```
Week.find(1).results.sum('box')
```

A get a SUM of column box an it works perfect!

But when I apply a filter in it:

```
Week.find(1).results.find(:all, :joins => [:seller],:conditions => ['sellers.user_id = ?', 1]).sum('caixas')
```

I get a error `NoMethodError: undefined method '+' for #<Result:0x103239e58>`

The object returned is the same I print It on console and don't see anything wrong.

Somebody knows something about it?

Tks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ActiveRecord#sum`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods.html#M002191) is an ActiveRecord method.

The first case works because `Week.find(1).results` returns an association proxy that exposes the same methods of Week class.

In the second case you are calling `#sum` on an Array object, not an ActiveRecord model.
If you want the second case to work, you should use a scope or an association proxy.

Change

```
Week.find(1).results.find(:all, :joins => [:seller],:conditions => ['sellers.user_id = ?', 1]).sum('caixas')
```

to

```
Week.find(1).results.scoped(:joins => [:seller], :conditions => ['sellers.user_id = ?', 1]).sum('caixas')
```